# How to show back button using Expo and React Router v6 NativeRouter

Tags: react-native, react-router, expo

I am new to React Native and I am using Expo to create a simple app with two routes. I am using the `Link` element to navigate to another route (and that works) but no Back button appears. What am I doing wrong? Can someone advise or point me to documentation or an example on how to do this in React Native?

```
export default function App() {
  return(
    <SafeAreaView>
      <NativeRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />}> </Route>
          <Route path="home/:id" element={<Details />}> </Route>
          <Route path="*" element={<Text>There's nothing here!</Text>} />
        </Routes>
      </NativeRouter>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

```
export default function Home() {
    let details = getDetails();
    return (
        <View>
            {details.map((d) => 
                <Link to={`/home/${d.id}`} key={d.id}>
                    <Text>{d.title}</Text>
                </Link>
            )}
        </View>
    );
}
```

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.8",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.5.0",
    "expo": "~44.0.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.2.0",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.64.3",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.10.1",
    "react-native-svg": "12.1.1",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.1",
    "react-router-native": "^6.2.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@types/react": "~17.0.21",
    "@types/react-native": "~0.64.12",
    "typescript": "~4.3.5"
  },
```

Comment: Are you rendering a back button anywhere in your app?

Comment: @DrewReese No, do I need to do that? If so, how do I do that?

Comment: Something like `const navigate = useNavigate();` and `const goBack = () => navigate(-1);`, then later `<Button onPress={goBack}>Back</Button>`.

Comment: @DrewReese Thanks for your helpful response. I wasn't aware that I would need to explicitly define that. I'm assuming that is something I would need to define on each route??

Comment: Not necessarily on each route, but usually just once in a header or layout component.

Comment: you could also simply use expo-router nowadays